# Is django-imagekit ready for Django 2.0?

Tags: django

Could you tell me whether django-imagekit is ready for Django 2.0?
They doesn't seem to have announced that. But they mention "Test against Django 2.0" for their tox.ini.

Comment: seems like a better place to ask this would be on their github repository issues page

Comment: I am using it in django 2.0 and it works without a problem but I just use the thumbnail function so I can not confirm anything beyond that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using it in Django 2.1.3 and it seems to work fine. Also, the TravisCI is [passing](https://travis-ci.org/matthewwithanm/django-imagekit/branches) for their feature branch 2.0